# In recognize handwritten digits, Why we should use 10 neurons in output layer, instead of 4 neurons?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have read chap1 in [neural networks and deep learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html), in part "A simple network to classify handwritten digits" (you can search with ctrl-f), I find a good problems : "Why we should use 10 neurons in output layer, instead of 4 neurons ?"

With 4 neurons, each neuron has value 0 or 1 then representing 2^4 = 16 > 10. So, why we don't use 4 neurons in output layer ?

Answer (score 5):

Each output neuron is responsible for single digit. Output neuron `i` (10 neurons in total) will return probability `[0,1)` that input digit is `i`. This way you know distribution of probabilities for each digit instead of just single output when you use them as bits (as in your example with 2^4).

Comment: @serhiyb is correct. by calculating logits for every possible class you can use cross entropy loss, which penalizes mistakes proportionally to degree of confidence. (ie misclassifications with high confidence incur a higher loss than misclassifications with low confidence.) this measure of model performance is better than accuracy.